# Is there any research on episodic-like memory in reptiles?

Tags: memory, animal-cognition, episodic-memory

I've been studying the area of episodic-like memory in non-human animals and reptiles seems to be really underrepresented (or not represented at all). Is there any research that I am missing? Anything that would point to reptiles remembering what, where and when of an event? The only ones I could find were related to spatial memory (what & where), like this: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.beproc.2019.103963

Comment: If this doesn't have success here, you could try our [biology.se] site.